# Windows Server 2008 R2 on the Intel D525MW motherboard

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, intel-atom

Has anyone installed Windows Server 2008 on this motherboard? I know Intel doesn't officially support windows servers on their Atom motherboards.

I would like to build a headless server, so video driver (or the lack of it) is not really an issue. But what about the other drivers?

Answer (score 1):

I use the Windows 7 drivers, and enable unsubscribed drivers. But it is not good idea. For another path, you can install Windows 7, on the another hard drive, and do the drivers search on it from the Windows Server 2008 r2.

<sub>PS: I'm sorry for my English, it's not my first language.</sub>